# when taking print out of my website its showing php code on page

Tags: php, html

i designed a table in bootstrap  and  which showing record by having  different column and when i am trying to take printout out of this page. its showing PHP code instead of what output page screen content , why ? any one help me here is picture . [image: it is example]

Comment: Show your php code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To ask an On Topic question, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [perfect question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try This CSS @media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

## What is happening

Bootstrap contains the following code:

```css
abbr[title]::after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_print.scss#L34)

This adds the destination of a link after the link, which explains why your links are followed by their destination in brackets.

## How to solve

You have 3 options

1. Leave the link text in so that people can see where the links go
2. Replace the text with blank to hide it
3. Replace the text with your own text so that it is more readable

Answer (score 0):

check your php code or may be you cannot save file .php extension
or check you can starting or ending tags of php not correct use between html tags

Comment: i do have save the file in .php extension. and al, the other things or correct .

Comment: [link] (http://cashoutjobs.com) [link] when i designed this then i was learning , and now i have to make website  printable  , hemp me sir

Comment: help me , how can i stop this

Comment: tell me what methods are using for print ?

Comment: like this in table  `<td><a  href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></a></td>
                                                     <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $file;?></a></td>`